# Check validity of given formula in First order logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Given that 
$$\exists x(\phi\rightarrow\psi)$$
and
$$\exists x\phi$$
are valid, 
where $x$ is the only, possibly, free variable in $\phi,\psi$. Then, does it follow that
$$\exists x\psi?$$

It does not seems that this is true, since, when trying to prove it, using Tarski's definition, we see that, due to the existential quantifiers, there should exist two, possibly different, elements $a,b$ in our universe, where $\phi$ and $\phi\rightarrow\psi$ are true, but, since they are not necessarily the same element, $\psi$ may not be true.

So, trying to find a counterexample, we get, evidently, that either $\phi$ should not be valid or $\psi$ should not be true for every interpetation $\mathfrak{A}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose $\psi\equiv\bot$, where $\bot$ represents falsity. (You can use something like $0=1$ or $P\land \neg P$ if you like.) Then $\exists x.\varphi\to\psi$ is equivalent to $\exists x.\neg\varphi$. So you know that $\exists x.\varphi$ and $\exists x.\neg\varphi$. It is easy to think up predicates that are sometimes true and sometimes false, e.g. $\varphi(x)\equiv (x = 1)$.

Comment: So, I consider a language $L$ that has a constant symbol, let $1$, and I create such predicates, right?

Comment: Since you are talking about (presumably semantic) validity, you define a [structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_(mathematical_logic)), $\mathcal M$ and then show $\mathcal M\vDash \exists x.\varphi$ and $\mathcal M\vDash\exists x.\neg\varphi$, but $\mathcal M\not\vDash\bot$. For example, you let the domain be $\{0,1\}$, $\varphi$ be a relation symbol, and interpret $\varphi$ as $\{1\}\subseteq\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Allright, now I got it! Thank you! :)

Comment: One more thing, can we find such a solution without using any kind of constant symbols? I mean, validity for a clause $\phi$ means that for every structure $\mathfrak{A}$ we have that $\mathfrak{A}\models\phi$. So, what I mean is, can we avoid the use of $0,1$, assuming our first order language $L$ contains only variables, the universal quantifier, $\{\neg,\rightarrow\}$ (or any other complete set) and the predicate symbol $=$ which stands for the usual equality? Or could we, possibly, use a "richer" language with some constant symbols, so as to have your example? Thanks again!

Comment: The example in the previous comment *doesn't* use any constant symbols. The only non-logical symbol in the language is the unary relation symbol $\varphi$. 0 and 1 in that example, are not part of the language. They are part of the meta-language (e.g. ZFC). The domain is part of the structure. For the exact same language, I could have had the domain $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ and the *interpretation* of $\varphi$ be $\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2=1\}$. This would be a different structure for the same language. It may help to *pedantically* keep clear what is in the syntax and what is in the semantics.

Comment: Hmm... So, one could say that, since $\mathfrak{A}$ is a structure with a non-empty universe $|\mathfrak{A}|$, we can find *at least one* element in its universe, which, in our example, is interpreted as $1$?